# Google Sheets: Formula to get data from other tab

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a Google Sheet to get an overview of all workshops/events we are hosting.

There is a tab **INPUT**. There is a column for Date, Month, Event, Location, Presenter, Language. *The column month is filled in automatically based on the date, with the month formula.*

Then I have a tab where I want to get an **overview of the events per month**. 
And another tab where I want to get an **overview per location and event**.

For now I used a formula which I already knew, this one:

**overview per location and event**

```
=QUERY(importrange("url of my document"; "INPUT!A1:F28");"select Col1,Col5,Col6 where (Col3= 'Welcome') and (Col4= 'Melle') order by Col2")
```

**overview of the events per month**

```
=QUERY(importrange("url of my document"; "INPUT!A1:F28");"select Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6 where (Col2= 1) order by Col2")
```

But I was wondering if there is an easier formula to get the same result. Now I am using importrange referring to the url of the document, but that seems to be a bit weird because I am working in only one sheet, I don't want to pull data from another sheet, just from another tab.

Can I use the importrange formula differently? Can I use vlookup? Arrayformula? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if you want to pull data from another tab of the document you are working on or you want to pull data from another tab of the "url of my document" and don't want to type the whole thing again.

Pulling  info from the same document but different tab using query would be as easy as replacing `importrange("url of my document"; "INPUT!A1:F28")` with `TabYouWant!A1:F28`